# How can I use delay on textview for show text?

Tags: java, android

When i click button first time. Program will random text. then when i press button again it will delay slow to show text

my code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.yeehaw);
    showRandom = !showRandom;
    t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(showRandom) {                                     
                    sleep(5);
                    mp.start();
                    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Why are you showing tags for java, c, c++, visual? Please choose the **one** appropriate language for your project.  Also, if Java, what GUI library?

Comment: i am newby for this board. am sorry i don't know

Comment: You can add the tag for android.

Comment: What do you *want to do* ? Your explanations are not clear at all. Please use a question mark in your question. Ask a real question. Give background to understand, and give code of you tried (as you did, but you only did that).

Answer (score 0):

Your context isnt clear from your question still i can see that you are trying to delay the thread execution by 5 ms that would not be noticible to you. Increase the sleep duration to see if you overcome you issue.

PFB the detail for the sleep method here

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Thanks!

Comment: i mean when i press button first time text will random. next i press button again and text will slow down same same lottory How can i do it